# Variable expected java vector

Tags: java, vector, swap

I'm writing code for swapping two elements in a `java.util.Vector`.
But I get to this error in this line:

```
public void swap(int i, int j) {
    Order temp = maxHeap.get(i);
    maxHeap.elementAt(i) = maxHeap.get(j); // variable expected 
    maxHeap.get(j) = temp; // variable expected
    swapCounter++;
}
```

So, how am I supposed to change the element of a vector node?
BTW Order is simply another class which is each node of the `vector` and `maxHeap` is my `vector`.

Comment: You can't assign the results of `maxHeap.get` to the rvalue returned by `maxHeap.elementAt`.

Comment: do you know what I should do instead?
@ElliottFrisch

Comment: At `maxHeap.get(j) = temp;` fragment `maxHeap.get(j)` doesn't return variable, but value and you can't assign value to value, it would be like trying to assign `2 = 0`, that makes no sense. Same about `maxHeap.elementAt(i) = maxHeap.get(j);`. You need to `set` new value at specified position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign the results of a function call to a rvalue; instead you use [`Vector.setElementAt(E, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#setElementAt-E-int-) like

```
public void swap(int i, int j) {
    Order temp = maxHeap.get(i);
    maxHeap.setElementAt(maxHeap.get(j), i);
    maxHeap.setElementAt(temp, j);
    swapCounter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a new value to the result of a method. Instead, you could use the [`set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#set-int-E-) method specified by the `List` interface:

```
public void swap(int i, int j) {
    Order temp = maxHeap.get(i);
    maxHeap.set(i, maxHeap.get(j);
    maxHeap.set(j, temp);
    swapCounter++;
}
```